# how to query mongodb based on object to get documents that contains one or more equal properties (Search)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, routes, koa

Im trying to figure out how to Post a search object to mongo, and find all documents that matches one or more properties stated in the search object.

eg if i have post a json object as this:

```
// searchObject
{
  "kind": "employee"
  "name": "casper",
  "email": "daniel@mail.com"
}
```

i want to get all documents that contains `"name": "casper"`or `"email":"daniel@mail.com"`or both from the employee collection.

this is what i have so far. but i dont know how to loop through my properties.

```
router.post('/search', async (ctx) => {
  const searchObject = Object.assign(ctx.request.body);
  const collection = searchObject.kind

  const result = await store[collection].find({
    $and: [{ searchObject }]
  })
  console.log('result', result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
router.post('/search', async ctx => {
  const { kind, ...searchObject } = ctx.request.body;
  const collection = searchObject.kind;
  const conditions = Object.keys(searchObject).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc.push({ [key]: searchObject[key] });
    return acc;
  }, []);

  const result = await store[collection].find({
    $or: conditions,
  });
  console.log('result', result);
});
```

Comment: hmm as i understand it we remove the kind attr with {kind, ...searchObject } (spread operator) .
Then creates a array containing each key: value pair from searchObject. 
and that one we use with the $or operator in mongo? 

I do get a conditions [ { key: undefined } ] when i try to:
console.log('conditions', conditions) 

- i guess the acc.push({ key: acc[k] }); should be: acc.push({ key: acc[key] }); ?

Comment: I still dont understand why i get undefined when i try to console.log the conditions.
should it not return a array of objects for me?

Comment: I fixed the wrong typo in my answer.
First, make sure the `ctx.request.body` is not `undefined`

Comment: the ctx.request.body is correct. but i still get undefined. ive created a sandbox (without the post, just a dummy object to see if the Object.keyd and .reduce works. but i still get the error. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-yonath-vid2u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: the only thing wrong now is that we need to set [ ] around key, like: cc.push({ [key]: searchObject[key] }); otherwise the key is "key" not "title" or "email". Tank you sir! 

the result from my mongo does still display all documents. not only the one that contains the properties defined in the searchObject

Answer (score 0):

add `if (key !== "kind")` condition in reduce function

```
router.post('/search', async ctx => {
const searchObject = ctx.request.body;
const collection = searchObject.kind;
const conditions = Object.keys(searchObject).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (key !== "kind") acc.push({ [key]: searchObject[key] });
    return acc;
}, []);

const result = await store[collection].find({
    $or: conditions,
});
console.log('result', result); 
});
```